# how to integrate the parallelism in my code

Tags: powershell

my code so far works one by one, but I need them to run in parallel:

this is my code.

```
$TIMESTAMP = Get-Date; 
$TIMESTAMP = $TIMESTAMP.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-07:00");

#Patterns
$DB_NAME_MIRROR = "mirroring_<X>(<Y>)";

$primarykey = $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BACKUP_KEY; 
#strdatabasebackup
$STORAGE_URI_BACKUP = "example/(<Y>)<X>.bacpac";

#Arrays 
$DB_ARRAY = @("dbdom_mpinto","dbdom_penalolen","dbdom_coquimbo","dbdom_elquisco","dbdom_temuco","dbdom_imelbosque","dbdom_lareina","dbdom_buin");

#Replace timestamp 
$DB_NAME_MIRROR = $DB_NAME_MIRROR.Replace('<Y>',$TIMESTAMP); 
$STORAGE_URI_BACKUP = $STORAGE_URI_BACKUP.Replace('<Y>',$TIMESTAMP);

#Debugging....
#Write-Host $DB_NAME_MIRROR;
#Write-Host $STORAGE_URI_BACKUP;

#Database import 
foreach ($DB in $DB_ARRAY)  {
    $DB_NAME_IMPORT = $DB_NAME_MIRROR.Replace('<X>',$DB);
    $URL_FILE_BACKUP = $STORAGE_URI_BACKUP.Replace('<X>',$DB);

    #Debugging
    Write-Host $DB_NAME_IMPORT   
    Write-Host $URL_FILE_BACKUP
}
```

how can I do my code with parallelism

Comment: Just to be clear, you're looking to do the `ForEach` block in parallel, right? This is just a general "How do I run the same code against multiple targets at the same time?" kind of question I'm guessing.

Comment: You can use `start-job` inside the loop to run the commands independently and they you would be able to capture the output using `receive-job`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do your 'multi-threading/parallel' effort.

- Jobs
- Workflows
- Runspaces

> Parallel processing with PowerShell

```
Start-Job -Name EventJob01 -ScriptBlock {Get-EventLog -Log system} -Credential domain01\user01


Workflow Some-TasksToRun
{
   <Commands>
}

$rp = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace(1,5)
$ps = [powershell]::Create()
$ps.RunspacePool = $rp
...
```

> 'blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/06/20/parallel-processing-with-powershell'
>
> See also for a good long discussion on Runspaces:
>
> 'serverfault.com/questions/626711/how-do-i-run-my-powershell-scripts-in-parallel-without-using-jobs'